# How to use lookahead and lookbehind in more than one capturing group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to use positive lookahead and lookbehind to extract data between parentheses and I need to use the same number of capture groups as there are number of parentheses. The problem I am facing is when I try to use more than one capture group then there are no matches but if I use only one group then it works fine. What changes do I have to make to my regex to make it match the appropriate data. The regex that I am using along with the data is [here](https://regexr.com/4i6mc). I want to use this in AWS Athena to read data from my S3 bucket objects.

I have tried various other ways but settled on this method with lookahead and lookbehind as it ensures that the parentheses is not captured.

```
((?<=VERS\=\()[^\)]*(?=\)))((?<=UUID\=\()[^\)]*(?=\)))
```

The expected result is that the first capture group captures data from first parentheses and the second group captures data from the second parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match either of those, you could add a pipe `|` which means an alternation between the 2 parts and take the lookarounds outside of the capturing group.

Note that you don't have to escape the `=` the the `)` inside the character class.

```
(?<=VERS=\()([^)]*)(?=\))|(?<=UUID=\()([^)]*)(?=\))
                         ^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IlpJwG/1)

Instead of using lookarounds, you might also match the 2 parts:

```
VERS=\(([^)]+)\);UUID=\(([^)]+)\);
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cxZPqN/2)

Comment: In your second option of doing regex without lookarounds, how would I proceed if one of the field didn't exist always, say UUID is optional.

Comment: @ChanduRaman If the second one can be optional, you could use an optional group https://regex101.com/r/T0OtzI/1

Comment: Additionally, i tried this out in AWS Athena which uses regex ser de but for some reason the value of all the columns is becoming null. Do you have any idea on the cause of this? and the pipe functionality also doesn't work in AThena

Comment: @ChanduRaman Did you try double escaping the backslashes? `String regex = "VERS=\\(([^)]+)\\);UUID=\\(([^)]+)\\);";` When I read the beginning of [this page](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r1.2.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/RegexSerDe.html) is says `if a row does not match the regex, then all columns in the row will be NULL` are you sure there is a match?

Comment: I have used double escaping the backslash as without it I get a different error. I am not what they exactly mean when they say that a row needs to get matched because my row of data has 14 parameters and out of them 10 do get matched and the rest of the column names are not present in the data itself due to which I used the optional capture like you suggested.